Why my query doesn't use a functional index in MySQL8
I have a mysql8 database with a table board, have a column name result(varchar(255));
result value can be any text. And i put 10 million records into board as a test.
I wanted to use below query,
SELECT * FROM board WHERE result LIKE '%wow';

It took almost 5 seconds. And I found out that queries with a wildcard(%) at the beginning  cannot use an index.
So, I created below functional index and modified that query can use idx_reverse_result.
CREATE INDEX idx_reverse_result ON board((REVERSE(result)));
SELECT * FROM board WHERE REVERSE(result) LIKE 'wow%';

I ran the query below to find out the execution plan.
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM board WHERE REVERSE(result) LIKE 'wow%';

But, the result like,



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
board
NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
9622368
100.00
Using where



did not use idx_reverse_result and always using full-table scan.
I tried FORCE INDEX (idx_reverse_result), but result was same.
Cardinality of idx_reverse_result index is 890,120.
Is there something I don't know? Thanks

It's a bug, reported in 2021, but apparently not fixed in any current version of MySQL. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104713 I tested MySQL 8.4.2 and it's still a bug in that version.

I didn't know that this was a bug occurred while using a functional index in a LIKE query. Thank you!

Does it work if you create a generated column with an index, and use the column in the query?
